# My Beautiful Soup code is returning TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I am using `Beautiful Soup` for web scraping and getting a TypeError here.

**My code is as follows :**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=asus&rh=n%3A300189&nav_sdd=aps&pd_rd_r=58b28d7d-1955-433b-b33b-b1b5dcf1f522&pd_rd_w=MJzan&pd_rd_wg=QG3cj&pf_rd_p=6d81377b-6d6c-4363-ae02-8fa202ed7b50&pf_rd_r=X0BDDAPN7TTW0ZT1REX6&qid=1583290662&ref=sxwds-sbc_c2")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
x = soup.find(Class='a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal')

for vari in x:
    print(vari.get_text())
```

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/intel/Desktop/Untitled-1.py", line 8, in <module>
    for vari in x:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I don't think my class id is wrong...

Comment: that's probably because BeautifulSoup is not finding an element with class 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal'. Just because in your browser you see it doesn't mean your code can.

Comment: Yeah I know, but the class is totally correct.

Comment: Try saving the html to a file and then open that file. I think ``str(soup)`` should work

Comment: I saved it to an html and I'm getting a captcha input page. probably amazon knows you are trying to parse their website and it's blocking you

Comment: So what to do now??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because Amazon is blocking your automated request.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=asus&rh=n%3A300189&nav_sdd=aps&pd_rd_r=58b28d7d-1955-433b-b33b-b1b5dcf1f522&pd_rd_w=MJzan&pd_rd_wg=QG3cj&pf_rd_p=6d81377b-6d6c-4363-ae02-8fa202ed7b50&pf_rd_r=X0BDDAPN7TTW0ZT1REX6&qid=1583290662&ref=sxwds-sbc_c2")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
with open("out.html", "w") as f:
   f.write(str(soup))
```

[image: out.html]

Comment: Okay, so is there any way out there? I mean I see many softwares scraping Amazon sites. Why didn't they get blocked?? Maybe there is something we can do...

Comment: You could try python-selenium